# Can you make an array of JTextFields in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I made 3x3 Magic Square Checker. I was just wondering how would I be able to store my 9 JTextFields in a array? 
This way I can loop through the 2d array and the JTextFields to quickly assign the values, because the way I'm storing my values is far from efficient...

```
    int[][] grid = new int[3][3];
    grid[0][0] = new Integer(one.getText());
    grid[0][1] = new Integer(two.getText());
    grid[0][2] = new Integer(three.getText());
    grid[1][0] = new Integer(four.getText());
    grid[1][1] = new Integer(five.getText());
    grid[1][2] = new Integer(six.getText());
    grid[2][0] = new Integer(seven.getText());
    grid[2][1] = new Integer(eight.getText());
    grid[2][2] = new Integer(nine.getText());
```

Comment: like `JTextFields [][] = new JTextFields [3][3];` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simplest way, if you want to do this in a loop, you should create JTextField objects in a List, array or in any list object supported by java. Because you want to get values in a certain order and do this in loop.

```
JTextField[] fields = new JTextField[9];
//set the index of text field
int fieldIndex = 0;
int[][] grid = new int[3][3];
for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<3; j++){
        //JTextField value will be string, if you want to get integer from string you should do this. Otherwise you can generate string matrix to keep values as a string.
        grid[i][j] = Integer.getInteger(fields[fieldIndex].getText());
        fieldIndex++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to store the JTextFields in an array or the Integer value in the array? This will store the Integer as you have it in your example code but you could easily change the assignment on line 7 to a new JTextField instead.

```
private static final int ROWS_NUM = 3;
private static final int COLS_NUM = 3;
int[][] grid = new grid[ROWS_NUM][COLS_NUM];
int counter = 0;
for(int i=0; i<ROWS_NUM; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<COLS_NUM; j++) {
        grid[i][j] = new Integer(++counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want store the JTextFields in an array and after running grid through a loop, I want it to store the values the user input in the JTextFields